# ImageJ and Normal Java

Tags: java, imagej

Hi i am making a java application for image processing. I am using normal java with imagebuffer. I want to use an imageJ code but i dont know how to combine it with my already written code.

Comment: Can you show (the relevant pieces of) that code?

Comment: imagebuffer or [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)? Please show some code.

Comment: Clarify your question and show some things you have tried.

Comment: its bufferedimage sorry....i want to use imageJ classes in an application i am making...i mean i want to embed it in my java code

Answer (score 2):

You can easily create an ImageJ RGB image from `BufferedImage` using the `ColorProcessor(java.awt.Image)` constructor.

To get the BufferedImage back, you can use method `createImage()` from `ColorProcessor` or `getBufferedImage()` from `ImagePlus`.

Here is a sample ImageJ plugin that retrieves the current image, coverts it to BufferedImage, closes the current image and opens a new one from the BufferedImage.

```
public class Sample implements PlugIn {

  public void run(String arg) {
    ImagePlus ip = IJ.getImage();
    BufferedImage bi = ip.getBufferedImage();
    ip.close();

    ImagePlus ip2 = new ImagePlus("from BufferedImage", new ColorProcessor(bi) );
    ip2.show();    
  }
}
```